# Why do I get this error in DLNMs (dlnm package) in R?

Tags: r

I have a question regarding dlnm package in R.
I am trying  to replicate a simple example of DLNMs (code below) which connects temperature to mortality.
It is straight-forward but when I try to insert my dataset (Daily_Data_MoT) I get:

> Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector
> of type 'any'

I am extremely new to R and I am pretty lost. I would appreciate any help!

```
library(dlnm)

head(Daily_Data_MoT,3)

cb1.temp <- crossbasis(Daily_Data_MoT$temp, lag=3, argvar=list(df=5),arglag=list(fun="strata",breaks=1))

library(splines)

model1 <- glm(death ~  cb1.temp + ns(time, 7*14) + dow, family=quasipoisson(), Daily_Data_MoT)

Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `time` object is not defined in the global environment,
because when I run this code (with `time` not defined) I get the same error.

```
> ns(time, 7*14)
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

If `time` is a variable contained in the `Daily_Data_MoT` data.frame, then
your remedy may be to adjust the code like this:

```
model1 <- glm(death ~  cb1.temp + ns(Daily_Data_MoT$time, 7*14) + dow, family=quasipoisson(), Daily_Data_MoT)
```

If this fixes the error, it suggests that `glm()` does not find `time`
when it is wrapped in `ns()`.

Comment: Yes thank you that was the mistake! Actually I wasn't reading my data correctly, as I confused the versions of the excel file I had uploaded. Stupid mistake but thank you for your help!